# Remove/hide browser address bar or toolbar web page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am creating web page using asp.net. Is it possible to remove/hide the browsers address bar or toolbar using Javascript for IE.

Nathiya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

It used to be possible to remove these in popups (foul things though popups are), but modern browsers make it impossible to remove the address bar as an anti-phishing measure.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript isn't supposed to change this kind of things.
You could open a pop up window without those things, however.

Comment: How to open an popup without url or addressbar.